# Size of prime products

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many primes are there that are $n$ bits long?

How many primes are there that are atmost $n$ bits long?

What is the number of bits in product of all primes that are $n$ bits long (with carry calculations included)?

What is the number of bits in product of all primes that are atmost $n$ bits long (with carry calculations included)?

with carry calculations included means to include the discrepancy caused by carries as well.
Some $n$ bit product produces $2n-1$ bits. While others produce $2n$ bits.

Comment: What do you mean by "carry calculations included"?

Comment: "What is the number of bits in product of primes that are $n$ bits long": either $2n-1$ or $2n$ (just like the number of bits in product of any two numbers that are $n$ bits long).

Answer (score 2):

The number of primes less than $m$ is traditionally called $\pi(m)$.

Using that we can answer the first two questions, in reverse order because that's makes it a little more obvious what is going on:

The number of primes at most $n$ bits long is $\pi(2^{n+1}-1)$ (as $2^{n+1}$ is obviously not primes the $-1$ is superflorous).

The numbers that are $n$ bit long are $2^{n-1}\ldots (2^n-1)$, the number of primes in this range is given by $\pi(2^n-1)-\pi(2^{n-1})$.

The prime number theorem tells us that:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{x/\log x} = 1
$$
(where $\log$ is the natural logarithm). That can give you some approximations (I believe they are quite good for numbers of a size that matters).

I think it's hard to say anything about the product of all primes in an interval.

Comment: How many bits is in $\pi(m)$ and how many bits is in the product?

Comment: As I said, I think it's hard to say anything about the product. I've added a little about about the prime number theorem, which might make it possible to calculate usable answers to your questions for specific values. I doubt you can do much better.

Comment: Please give me the best answer for product you have.

Comment: I don't know too much about this but aren't there asymptotic estimates for the sum $\sum \ln(p)$? Then you can exponentiate to tell you about products of primes.

Comment: @fretty: You might be right, but I would be careful with exponentiating an estimate, errors can grow really fast.

Comment: Can you verify the exponent in "The numbers that are $n$ bit long are $2^n ... 2^{n+1}-1$"?  That says the numbers that are 2 bits long are 4 to 7.  But those have the third bit set, so are 3 bits long.

Comment: @DanaJ:Right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods for producing the the answers computationally.

> How many primes are there that are n bits long?

```
perl -Mntheory=:all -E 'for my $n (1..20) { say "$n ", prime_count(1<<($n-1),(1<<$n)-1); }'

1 0      there are no 1-bit primes
2 2      2 and 3 are 2-bit primes
3 2      5 and 7 are 3-bit primes
4 2      11 and 13 are 4-bit primes
5 5      17,19,23,29,31
6 7
7 13
8 23
9 43
10 75
11 137
12 255
13 464
14 872
15 1612
16 3030
17 5709
18 10749
19 20390
20 38635
```

This should work to 63 bits (64 if you adjust the end point), though it's pretty slow after 51 bits or so.  Or use a table (e.g. [Kulsha](http://www.primefan.ru/stuff/primes/table.html) or [Oliveira e Silva](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/primes.html)) and you can go all the way to 2^86 quickly.

> How many primes are there that are at most n bits long?

```
perl -Mntheory=:all -E 'for my $n (1..10) { say "$n ", prime_count((1<<$n)-1); }'

1 0      there are no primes of 0 or 1 bit length
2 2      2,3            all fit in 2 bits
3 4      2,3,5,7        all fit in 3 bits
4 6      2,3,5,7,11,13  all fit in 4 bits
5 11
6 18
7 31
8 54
9 97
10 172
```

Barring the value for 2 because of the definition, this is [OEIS A007053](https://oeis.org/A007053) and can be read directly from many tables.  The OEIS page now has up to $2^{86}$.

> What is the number of bits in product of all primes that are n bits long

```
perl -Mntheory=:all -E 'use Math::GMP; for my $n (2..20) { my $prod = vecprod(@{primes(1<<($n-1),(1<<$n)-1)}); say "$n ", Math::GMP->new($prod)->sizeinbase_gmp(2); }'

2 3             2*3 = 6 = 0b110 is 3 bits
3 6             5*7 = 35 = 0b100011 is 6 bits
4 8             11*13 = 143 = 0b10001111 is 8 bits
5 23
6 40
7 85
8 174
9 368
10 717
11 1445
12 2946
13 5824
14 11818
15 23458
16 47118
17 94497
18 188671
19 378297
20 755438
```

There are various ways to get the bit size, this one seemed best, but the core bigint module can do it also.  This gets pretty slow at 26+ bits where the product is 48M bits.  Pari/GP might be faster here.

> What is the number of bits in product of all primes that are at most n bits long

As above, just remove the first argument to `primes()`.